# For how many days back will jawbone support retrieving data from the rest api?

Tags: jawbone

I would like to know for how many days back will Jawbone allow a user to retrieve his data. Is it for one month, one year or from the time he has actually connected the device and started recording the data?

Answer (score 0):

Jawbone saves all data collected through the UP platform and allows API access to the complete history.

Once a user grants data access to a third party application through OAuth, that application can query the user's entire history for the types of data authorized.